# Eigenvalue equation under neumann boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $c(x)\in L^{\infty}(0,a)$, a>0. We consider the problem

$-u''+c(x)u=\lambda u(x),\quad x\in (0,a),$

under the boundary conditions $u'(0)=u'(a)=0$.

Show that $u>0 $ in $[0,a]$ and that $\lambda\leq \int_0^a c(x)dx$.

So far I integrated the equation to get a first relation: $\int_0^a c(x)u(x)dx=\lambda\int_0^a u(x) dx$, and also multiplying by $u$ and integrating by parts we get another relation: $\int_0^a u'^2(x)dx+\int_0^a c(x)u^2(x)dx=\lambda\int_0^a u^2(x) dx$, but I cannot conclude the things that are asked. Can you help me?

Comment: There is something missing. Set $c(x)=\lambda, \forall x\in(0,a)$, we obtain $u''(x)=0$, such that every $u(x)=c$ with $c\in\mathbb{R}$ would be a solution.

Comment: In fact, for the operator $d^2/dx^2$ under neumann boundary conditions, the first eigenvalue is $0$, and every constant diferent from $0$ is an eigenfunction. The problem is to show that $u>0$ or $u<0$, but cannot change sign.

Comment: And there is no restriction on $c(x)$ (positive or negative)? Have you tried multiplying by $u'(x)$ and integrating?

Comment: No, there is no restriction for $c(x)$. It can change sign. I tried what you said, but I didn't get the result.